# how to download file from ftp in a local windows application gridview cell content click

Tags: c#, winforms

i have displayed some files from ftp in my local windows application data gridview. i put a button in datagridview,when i click that download button which is shown in datagridveiw ftp files donwload please help me

```
    1) how to download files from the following data gridview , these file get from ftp server
i have the follwing download method.
 public bool DownloadFile(string url, string fileName, string userName, string password, string destinationPath)
    {

        String directoryPath = string.Empty;
        Stream responseStream = null;
        FileStream writeStream = null;
        MemoryStream memoryStream = null;

        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@url + "/" + fileName.Trim());
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.Timeout = -1;
            request.UsePassive = true;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {

                responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                responseStream.Close();
                responseStream.Dispose();

                string filePath = destinationPath;
                //filePath = filePath + "//" + "Reciepts//";
                if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
                }

                if (!File.Exists(@filePath + "/" + fileName))
                {
                    writeStream = new FileStream(@filePath + "/" + fileName.TrimEnd().TrimStart(), FileMode.Create);
                    memoryStream.WriteTo(writeStream);
                    memoryStream.Close();
                    memoryStream.Dispose();
                    writeStream.Close();

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

e.g [image]

Comment: Whats the problem? Problem is with download or with click on cell?

Comment: I'll post it in a minute:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //if click is on new row or header row
    if( e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex || e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    //Handle Button Click
    //dataGridView1.Columns[YourColumnIndex] works too
    if( e.ColumnIndex  == dataGridView1.Columns["YourColumnName"].Index)
    {
        //Do the stuff for button click
        //for example DownloadFile(url, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["YourFileNameColumn"].Value.ToString(), username, password, destinationPath)
        MessageBox.Show("Button Clicked");
    }
}
```

Remember you can get value of a cell by its column index and by its column name, for example:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString()
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value.ToString()
```

Comment: i did the follwing


private void dataGridViewResponses_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex==0)
            {
                FTPUtility obj = new FTPUtility();
                obj.DownloadFile("ftp://ip address/Responses/", "exit.png", "edexcrawler", "edexcrawler123", @"C:\Users\razim\Desktop\Desktop Application\Desktop Application\Temp");
         
            }
        }
i give static file name "exit.png" how i can get from datagridveiw

Comment: @RazimKhan MessagBox is just for example, instead of messagebox, call `DownloadFile(url, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["YourFileNameColumn"].Value.ToString(), username, password, destinationPath)`

Comment: @RazimKhan You can get value of a cell this way: `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["YourFileNameColumn"].Value.ToString()`

Comment: i have given path where my files will be donwloaded, which is @"C:\Users\razim\Desktop\Desktop Application\Desktop Application\Temp
 but when i install some where else , there should not available that path, i want to give a dynamic path, @Reza

Comment: @RazimKhan you can simply show a `SaveFileDialog` to the users to select the path. Also you can use more Ideas about where the file can be saved. Feel free to notify me if you need more help on that :)

Comment: i did that like which is forevery user
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

Comment: @RazimKhan This is a good idea, but saving on desktop may be annoying for user and save in his documents folder may be better. Also you can provide a setting for user to keep his desired path configurable. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603138/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-c-sharp-windows-application